# Layout below not working in android relative xml

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I'm confused why `android:layout_below` is not working, I just need to put the button below the border line and I don't wanna use `android:layout_marginTop="570dp` because the android phone has different sizes, Is somebody know how can I arrange the layout of this? it helps me a lot thanks in advance.

This is what I want to achieve

[image]
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_fieldset_background"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linearl">

    </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:text="Cash Card Scanner"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SCAN"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearl"
          
            />
</RelativeLayout>
```

*Drawable selector_fieldset_background.xml*

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
<stroke
    android:width="2dip"
    android:color="#25000000" />
</shape>
```

Comment: That `<Button>`'s parent is the `<LinearLayout>`, not the `<RelativeLayout>`. A `LinearLayout` will just ignore that attribute, and the `RelativeLayout` will never know about it, since `layout_*` attributes do not propagate up whole hierarchy. They only apply to the immediate parent. Are you sure you even need that `<LinearLayout>`?

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks for your response, I edit now the code and change it to the RelativeLayout but the button didn't show at all

Comment: You have it laid out below the `linearl` `RelativeLayout`, but that's `match_parent` for height, so it's pushing the `Button` out the bottom of the parent `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: @MikeM.  It's need to be wrap_content? I tried but it do the same, can you help me

Comment: I don't know what you mean, but that `android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"` on the `<RelativeLayout>` is pushing the `<Button>` away, too. It's not just pushing the `<RelativeLayout>` away from the parent. You generally don't want to use margins to position or size `View`s. If you want that `<RelativeLayout>` a certain height, then set its `layout_height`, not a margin. The `layout_below` on the `<Button>` should work as expected then, assuming it's not otherwise covered or pushed off-screen. If you need more control over placement than `RelativeLayout` allows, you might try `ContstraintLayout`

Comment: If you don't really need the bottom of that `<RelativeLayout>` exactly 100dp away, and you're just trying to get the `<Button>` on the bottom, you can align it to the bottom of the parent first, and then add a `layout_above` to the `<RelativeLayout>` instead. I'm not really sure what exactly you're going for, though.

Comment: @Mike M. Thanks for the response , I change the layout height from `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to `android:layout_height="500dp"`  and I remove the margin then now it works but the problem is their the mobile phone has a different size at all the button will not static positioned since I set the height of the button to 500dp, do you have idea of this thanks in advance

Comment: Well, you had the same basic problem with the 100dp bottom margin, too, so I'm not sure what you're going for specifically. Do you really want that exact 100dp gap, with the `<Button>` inside that? Then you might have to switch to something like `ConstraintLayout`, 'cause `RelativeLayout` isn't really designed to do that. Otherwise, if you just need the `<Button>` between the bottom of the `<RelativeLayout>` and the parent, then you can do as I described above and align the `<Button>` first, and then add a `layout_above` to the `<RelativeLayout>`.

Comment: @MikeM. thanks for your idea,  Actually this is what I want the design [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLKf7.png) What can you suggest? should I use `ConstraintLayout` ? the button should under the box border

Comment: If I'm following that correctly, then something like this might be what you want: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nlL8bB5j5xT4bIlVTt0-Jbx9AWR3qRPY/view?usp=sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this, works for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_fieldset_background"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linearl"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
        >

    </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:text="Cash Card Scanner"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:text="SCAN"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```